# Sending data to SSH client from server implemented in SSH Apache Mina

Tags: ssh, mina

We are new to Apache MINA SSH server and currently working on reverse SSH

Here are the steps followed

1. SSHD server started on a port, server implements `StreamIOHandler`
2. Upon receiving a connection from the Device, we have `IOSession`, `InputStream` and `OutputStream`

Questions:

1. How to use this `IoSession`, to write the data back to the device.
2. Can we get `ClientChannel`/`ClientSession` associated with the `IoSession`. (or) these only applies, when the connection is initiated from the client to server not the otherway?
3. What are `IOInputStream` and `IOOuputStream` classes

It would be of great help if someone share some programs

Thanks
Vikram

Comment: What does it mean *"write the data back to the device"*?

Comment: When the device connects to the application, we get the IoSession. In case of Netconf protocol, when the channel is opened/created, we (both app and device) have to exchange the hello messages, this is where the need raises to write data back to server using IoSession

Comment: I do not see any `StreamIOHandler` in Apache MINA (0.14).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are implementing NETCONF  protocol over SSH.

When the NETCONF is used over SSH, it is implemented as "netconf" channel.

So I assume you should implement an SSH subsystem in the MINA, similarly to the `SftpSubsystem` class, which implements `Command` interface

```java
public interface Command {
    void setInputStream(InputStream in);
    void setOutputStream(OutputStream out);
    ...
}
```

Using `setOutputStream` you get an `OutputStream`. Whatever you write to the stream is sent to the (SSH) client.